# C# The base virtual properties of IdentityUser are not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, virtual

I created an AppUser class that inherits from the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, looks like the code below, but the base properties of IdentityUser are not visible unless I override them? Shouldn't the public virtual fields of IdentityUser be accessible via inheritance through the AppUser class?

This is happening in a 'class' project, output is a DLL, targeting .Net 4.6.2 and I think I have all the required packages. I can use the AppUser class; create users, create roles, add user to roles, etc. Just can't figure out why the behavior of inheritance seems to work differently here then in my other projects?

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    // why do I need to override these to get access to them
    public override string Id { get => base.Id; set => base.Id = value; }
    public override string Email { get => base.Email; set => base.Email = value; }
    public override string UserName { get => base.UserName; set => base.UserName = value; }
    public override string PasswordHash { get => base.PasswordHash; set => base.PasswordHash = value; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You should post that as the answer, since it is correct. To follow up, the missing fields were in a console project that was calling the class/DLL project. When I added the Identity.Framework package to the Console project the virtual fields became visible in the caller project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` in your project by adding the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework`, because that's where these properties have been declared. Only referencing the DLL where `AppUser` is declared is not sufficient.